# ggplot2, multiple variables for a line plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a line graph in R with multiple variables as the following data frame:
[Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSMN4.png)

I would like to get a plot as the next one:
[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNkOQ.png)

I have tried different methods but not being able to get this done, any suggestion?

Comment: Hi Carlos, you should have a read of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so people have the best chance of being able to help you. On first glance however, I'd question why you want a line graph for your data. A bar chart might be more suitable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your support, I already had a look and your suggestion makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started, but I would tend to agree with Michael that a line plot may not be the way to go.

```
test <- data.frame(Name = c('M','D','T','H','P'),
                   Ball_Control = c(48,31,23,34,22),
                   Dribbling = c(30,13,13,10,12),
                   Marking = c(10,13,11,12,11),
                   Sliding_Tackle = c(11,13,16,18,12))
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df.gathered <- gather(test,key = 'Parameter',value = 'Value',2:5)

ggplot(df.gathered, aes(x = Parameter, y = Value, group = Name, col = Name))+geom_line()+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,60), breaks = seq(0,60,10))
```

Comment: Hi Balter, thanks so much, it really worked for was after, btw I will follow your suggestion and change the plot type.